# Why does this Selenium XPath expression fail to return results when concat() is used?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xpath, selenium, concatenation

When I use the following XPath expression in Selenium, it works correctly.  Its finds an ancestor div of the current element which contains a certain string in its class attribute:

```
inputEl.findElement(By.xpath("ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'x-form-item')]")).getAttribute("class")
```

The answer it gives is `"x-form-item "` (notice the trailing space).

However, I want ancestors which precisely have the `x-form-item` class, and not other classes like `x-form-item-label`.  So I changed the expression as follows:

```
inputEl.findElement(By.xpath("ancestor::div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' x-form-item ')]")).getAttribute("class")
```

However, once this in place, Selenium is unable to find the element.  It gives this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == ancestor::div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' x-form-item ')] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

At first I thought I had some kind of mistake, so to simplify, I removed the leading/trailing space.  Presumably this is semantically the same as my very first, working query:

```
inputEl.findElement(By.xpath("ancestor::div[contains(concat('', @class, ''), 'x-form-item')]")).getAttribute("class")
```

However, this also fails:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == ancestor::div[contains(concat('', @class, ''), 'x-form-item')] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

So my fundamental question is, why are these two resulting in different strings?

- `@class`
- `concat('', @class, '')`

Note: I am using the IEDriver with IE9

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you don't even need concat(' ', @class, ' '). 
You should be able to use

```
By.xpath("ancestor::div[contains(@class, ' x-form-item ')]")
```

because you're looking for ' x-form-item ' in the '@class' tag, not looking in the ' @class ' tag.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know beforehand that the class is "embedded" between other class names.  For example, the class attribute could contain "x-form-item class1 class2", or it could be like "class1 class2 x-form-item", or even just "x-form-item".  So none of those would match the expression without the concat.

Comment: Can you provide the full xpath?